# How to add Convex hull (or ellipse) for CCA plot in R

Tags: r, plot, ellipse, convex-hull

I have a dataset with 10 communities and 4 environmental variables taken along 60 sites. The [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6wvM.jpg) created CCA  on vegan method. I faced the problem with building a convex hull (and ellipse) for mark community points of plot. The search a some R code did not give the result for this version of the code. Source file can be download on the link [data.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B__YJJGdn5NkeUpVRGNRQlYxa1U/view?usp=sharing).

```
library(vegan)
df <- read.csv2('data.csv')    
df.env <- df[,2:6] # Vars of environments
df.sp <- df[,7:88] # Vars of species
mod <- cca(df.sp ~ ENV1 + ENV2 + ENV3, df.env)
scl <- 2
colvec <- c("darkorange", "blueviolet", "forestgreen", "green", "deeppink", "gray", "black", "skyblue", "cadetblue", "blue")
plot(mod, type="n", scaling=scl)
with(df.env, points(mod, display="sites", col=colvec[Community],
                            scaling=scl, pch=21, bg=colvec[Community]))
```

Comment: can you please bring the necessary part of the code here?

Comment: I found a solution for convex hull  `ordihull(mod, df.env$Community, lty = 2, col = "gray")` But the contours are obtained in one color, and it is necessary in different colors to appropriate vector colvec in code.